# .htaccess not working on linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, .htaccess

I have defined some URL Rewriting rules in .htaccess file

Its working fine on localhost in windows

But when I uploaded it on server that is linux based, it stopped to work
I have found the problem on this [link](http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems)

> Files and directory names starting with a dot are treated as hidden files by Unix, Linux & Mac. The htaccess file is hidden so it doesn’t distract from normal web content like HTML files. See hidden files for more information.
>   Without the dot at the beginning, Apache will ignore the htaccess file.

But I did not find the solution ...

Comment: Could be a silly question, but does .htaccess file name starts with a dot in the live server? If so, why do you think that's the problem?

Comment: yes but it hides.. And I think it might uses dot as an identifier and treats the file name without dot.. It can be a problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make sure that AllowOverride is enabled (AllowOverride all) in httpd.conf (many distribs have default as none)

if it is not that, you may have to post the actual htaccess for more help

Comment: I know this post is ancient, but maybe it can help somebody: Your httpd.conf file might be called apache2.conf based on your installation. Also the option is called "AllowOverride" without a tailing "s".

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is indeed AllowOverride ... I'm surprised it did not come up sooner. I corrected the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that module 'mod_rewrite' is loaded in your server. To check this use phpinfo() and then search for 'loaded modules'.